# Heroku automatically performed maintenance on my databases and now my app's don't connect

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I can launch my application still, and load a page that doesn't utilize any data from the pg database, but as soon as I hit a page that would look up data I get a time out error

```
2019-10-04T05:53:38.387579+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/sessions/login" host=get-organized.herokuapp.com request_id=735daa05-c11b-4da6-a7c5-90f8ae46759a fwd="73.158.160.78" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
201
```

These apps used to work fine. I have newer apps that didn't have the maintenance done and they still work fine. I have no idea how to further troubleshoot this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your database url likely changed during maintenance. It's probably hard coded somewhere in your application. You should be reading `$DATABASE_URL` out of the environment for the connection string rather than hardcoding it.

Comment: That was it! Don't remember ever hard coding it, but I suppose I must have. Thank you so much!